# (solved) How to glue syringe?

Tags: robotic-arm

I foud tons of answer how glue with syringe, but I need to glue syriges together to be airtight and glue some silicon tube there too  and cannot find a hint how to do it.

Does anybody know what glue does stick with syringe (eventually dissolve it a little)?

Comment: From your "robotic-arm" tag I'm guessing that you're looking to glue your robotic arm together. However, that doesn't seem to be of importance, so I think that this question belongs in an other StackExhange site like Engineering.

Comment: Ok, how to move it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used just hot soldering rod and it went well. I need to keep the heat low, but was able to solder the plastick together to be airtight. Just to be sure more I use the hot glue afteward to enforse the connections and make them more smooth. Not exactly nice looking, but works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this question isn't really appropriate for this forum. That said, if you search "syringe plastic material," you'll find this Stack Exchange answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65887/what-kind-of-materials-are-plastic-syringes-made-from, which suggests many syringes are made of polypropylene. If indeed that's what your syringes are made from, go get some glue appropriate for that material.